# Unable to create spatial database for geodjango on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to install PostGIS for MacOS X and uptil now this is what i got

```
PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0

 -------------- Compiler Info ------------- 
  C compiler:           gcc -g -O2
  C++ compiler:         g++ -g -O2

 -------------- Dependencies -------------- 
  GEOS config:          /usr/local/bin/geos-config
  GEOS version:         3.3.3
  PostgreSQL config:    /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config
  PostgreSQL version:   PostgreSQL 9.1.3
  PROJ4 version:        48
  Libxml2 config:       /usr/bin/xml2-config
  Libxml2 version:      2.7.3
  JSON-C support:       yes
  PostGIS debug level:  0
  Perl:                 /usr/bin/perl

 --------------- Extensions --------------- 
  PostGIS Raster:       disabled
  PostGIS Topology:     enabled

 -------- Documentation Generation -------- 
  xsltproc:             /usr/bin/xsltproc
  xsl style sheets:     
  dblatex:              
  convert:              
  mathml2.dtd:          http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd
```

Does this mean that PostGIS is now installed? Why is the PostGIS Raster disabled?

Also when i follow the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#creating-a-spatial-database-template-for-postgis) I am getting this error

```
createdb -E UTF8 template_postgis
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

Then i checked for the command

```
sudo su - postgres
```

and it returns 1 for `echo $?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that PostGIS is configured, as the first line says.

Typically you proceed with `make` and `make install`. After this is done you'll have PostGIS libraries ready, but you'll have to create PostGIS support functions on the database level, something like this: `psql -c spatial_ref_sys.sql`

I would recommend consulting also the [official docs](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html).

Your error message means that you're trying to connect to the database with the user / to the database that doesn't exists there. By default, PostgreSQL tools will try username / database that match your current unix user, which seems to be `root`.

And keep in mind that it is a very bad practice to work under `root` account.